# Expected value of sum of dice roll (one 6 side and one 10 side dice)

Tags: probability

You have 2 dice, one 6-sided dice and one 10-sided dice. You get the dollar amount of the sum of the 2 dice. If unsatisfied with the current roll, you may pay 1 dollar to re-roll. How much would you pay to play the game, or what is the expected value of the game?

Comment: Similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465651/expected-value-of-game-involving-100-sided-die?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several strategies, and the best seems to be to reroll on $9$ or less and stop with $10$ or more, which gives an expected payout of $\frac{293}{27}=10.8518518518519$ just above $\$10.85$

---

**Reroll on $8$ or less**

Let's say we reroll on $8$ or less and stay with $9$ or greater. The probabilty of rolling $9$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6+6+6+5+4+3+2+1}{60}=\frac{33}{60}
$$
so on average, it takes $\frac{60}{33}$ rolls to get $9$ or greater paying on average $\frac{27}{33}$ dollars to get there. The expected payout of $9$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6\cdot9+6\cdot10+6\cdot11+5\cdot12+4\cdot13+3\cdot14+2\cdot15+1\cdot16}{6+6+6+5+4+3+2+1}=\frac{380}{33}
$$
Thus, the expected value of this strategy is $\frac{380}{33}-\frac{27}{39}=\frac{353}{33}=10.6969696969697$

---

**Reroll on $9$ or less**

Let's say we reroll on $9$ or less and stay with $10$ or greater. The probabilty of rolling $10$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6+6+5+4+3+2+1}{60}=\frac{27}{60}
$$
so on average, it takes $\frac{60}{27}$ rolls to get $10$ or greater paying on average $\frac{33}{27}$ dollars to get there. The expected payout of $10$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6\cdot10+6\cdot11+5\cdot12+4\cdot13+3\cdot14+2\cdot15+1\cdot16}{6+6+5+4+3+2+1}=\frac{326}{27}
$$
Thus, the expected value of this strategy is $\frac{326}{27}-\frac{33}{27}=\frac{293}{27}=10.8518518518519$

---

**Reroll on $10$ or less**

Let's say we reroll on $10$ or less and stay with $11$ or greater. The probabilty of rolling $11$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6+5+4+3+2+1}{60}=\frac{21}{60}
$$
so on average, it takes $\frac{60}{21}$ rolls to get $11$ or greater paying on average $\frac{39}{21}$ dollars to get there. The expected payout of $11$ or greater is
$$
\frac{6\cdot11+5\cdot12+4\cdot13+3\cdot14+2\cdot15+1\cdot16}{6+5+4+3+2+1}=\frac{266}{21}
$$
Thus, the expected value of this strategy is $\frac{266}{21}-\frac{39}{21}=\frac{227}{21}=10.8095238095238$