# 100-die ev problem: intuition for strategy

Tags: probability, expected-value, game-theory, dice

A question from a probability book I saw:

> You are given a 100-sided die. After you roll once, you can choose to
> either get paid the dollar amount of that roll OR pay one dollar for
> one more roll. What is the expected value of the game? (There is no
> limit on the number of rolls.)

A few StackExchange posts talk about this problem, here's one: [Expected value of game involving 100-sided die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465651/expected-value-of-game-involving-100-sided-die?noredirect=1&lq=1.And) all use the same optimal strategy: reroll until you have a die value greater than V.

But I don't understand why that's optimal. For example, the answer they give is stop rolling when you reach a die value of 87 or more. But what if you always get rolls below that, and thus, never actually payout?

Three questions:

- How can one prove this is the optimal strategy?
- What does it mean to say this game or this die is memoryless?
- Is this still the optimal strategy if you have a finite number of dice rolls?

Comment: Let me point out that you will eventually roll at least an $87$ with probability $1$ (that is, almost surely).

Comment: True. Since this logic doesn't hold with a finite number of die rolls, does this strategy no longer work? Is there some "memory" now?

Comment: Yes. If you're on your last roll, obviously you'll take whatever you have (you have no choice). If you're on your second-to-last roll, you'll take anything in the upper half, approximately. And so on. To get exact figures, we have to do some minor calculations.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that does make sense, I've seen that approach before.