# Let's play a dice game

Tags: probability, dice

Roll a die with 100 faces, labeled from 1 to 100.

1. You get to roll once and receive the amount of dollars labeled on the face.  How much would you like to pay for this roll?
2. How much would you pay if you can re-roll the dice if you are unsatisfied with the first outcome?
3. You can roll the dice infinitely many times, and each roll costs 1 dollar except the first one.  What is your strategy?

My thoughts:

1. The expectation of a 100 faces dice is 50.5, so this is the fair value.
2. If I can re-roll once, I would re-roll if I rolled between 1 and 50.   Now the expectation would be $0.5 * 50.5 + 0.5 * 75.5 = 63$.
3. I guess my strategy would be keep re-rolling until the expectation improvement would be less than the cost of 1 dollar to re-roll? Can someone give me a closed form solution ?

Comment: 1,2: perhaps you mean what is the maximum amount that I'm willing to pay? If I have enough money to make up for my loss, 50 is the maximum I would pay.

3.The outcome of the experiment is independent of the amount of rolls I get. Therefore I'd keep rolling the die indefinitely for 1 dollar.

Comment: 3. You can roll infinite times with no strategy at all because you at least win a dollar in each roll, i.e. you never lose money.

Comment: well, the objective is to maximize your profit, of course. If I don't care about maximizing my profit I should just stop at the first toss since my expected pay off would be 50.5 and obviously this is better than rolling indefinitely.

Comment: I did a Monte Carole simulation and the answer is pretty close to 86, can someone give a analytical solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your answers for $1$ and $2$ are right.

For $3$, say you reroll if you roll at most $x$. Then your expected payoff is

$$
E=\frac x{100}(E-1)+\left(1-\frac x{100}\right)\frac{x+1+100}2\;,
$$

and solving for $E$ yields

$$
E=\frac{10100-3x-x^2}{2(100-x)}\;.
$$

Then setting the derivative with respect to $x$ to zero yields

$$
10100-3x-x^2=(2x+3)(100-x)
$$

with solution $x=10(10\pm\sqrt2)$. Only the smaller solution is feasible, $x=10(10-\sqrt2)\approx85.86$, and substituting the two adjacent integers, $85$ and $86$, into the expression for $E$ yields $\frac{262}3\approx87.33$ for $x=85$ and $\frac{1223}{14}\approx 87.36$ for $x=86$.

Thus a maximal profit of about $\$87.36$ is achieved if you reroll whenever you have at most $86$.